# In R, how to select as set of columns from each data frame in a list of data frames?

Tags: r, select, dplyr

Trying to select the first 3 columns of each data frame in a list of data frames (allDFs) using this code:

```
for(i in 1:length(allDFs)) {
  allDFs[i] <- allDFs[i] %>% select.list(., 1, 2, 3)
}
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Error in select.list(., 1, 2, 3) : 
  'title' must be NULL or a length-1 character vector (edited)
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R solutions:

```
lapply(allDFs, "[", 1:3)
```

Or:

```
Map(function(x)x[,1:3], allDFs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` :

```
lapply(allDFs, function(x) x[, 1:3])
```

Or with `dplyr`/`purrr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(allDFs, ~.x %>% select(1:3))
```